# How can I get online time for a Jenkins Node

Tags: jenkins

We would like to bring a Jenkins slave node back online after a specific operation involving updates to the node, then rebooting the node.

The intent is to ensure that when that node is know to have been updated, we monitor it, and when it is online again, signal to our schedulers that they can start allocating resources on that node again.

The problem is that online is not enough, as asking to reboot may not mean the computer does so immediately, so the Jenkins node may stay online for a while. So the idea is to see if the time since this node was brought online in Jenkins has suddenly dropped, and use this as a trigger.

However, I've not yet found a suitable way to get the time a Jenkins node was last brought online.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code below, but it could lead you in the right direction.
You can execute Groovy script:

```
connectTime = aSlave.getComputer().getConnectTime();
```

Links:
[Display info about nodes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+Information+About+Nodes)
[Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console)
[Determine Slave Up/Down TIme](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Determine-Slave-Up-Down-Time-td4083878.html)